# Webpack, gun, cannot resolve files, etc, gun require cannot resolve module 'fs'

Tags: webpack, gun

I'm working on a electron app with gundb. After getting everything else working I did a `npm install --save gun`. It completed with this warn:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

When I try to:

```
require('gun');
var endpoints;
var gun = Gun(endpoints);
```

I get a very long list of errors I can't make since of. They start with:

```
.../node_modules/fs doesn't exist
.../node_modules/fs.webpack.js doesn't exist
.../node_modules/fs.web.js doesn't exist
.../node_modules/fs.js doesn't exist
.../node_modules/fs.json doesn't exist
```

And the following cannot resolve:

```
@ ./~/gun/lib/file.js 14:10-23
@ ./~/gun/lib/wsp.js 61:39-52
@ ./~/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js 15:10-2
@ ./~/options/lib/options.js 6:9-2
@ ./~/aws-sdk/lib/api_loader.js 1:9-22
@ ./~/aws-sdk/lib/services.js 1:9-22
```

I'm on Linux. Is fsevent a dependency of gun npm?

**UPDATE**
To remove as many other variables as possible, I reduced my package.json file down to only electron....eliminating possible issues with webpack, and other dependencies. I also deleted my node_modules and did a fresh `npm install & npm install gun`.

That revealed a more useful error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Gun is not defined                gun.js:1470
```

Which pointed to:

```
if(typeof window !== "undefined"){ Gun.request = request }
if(typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports){ module.exports.request = request }
```

Comment: That fsevent warning is pretty normal. They are unconnected.

Comment: This question might also be helpful for other Webpack / GUN errors (for those that clicked on this question from Google but it wasn't the right issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001582/running-gunjs-with-reactjs-and-webpack-throws-reference-error-in-console/39003291#39003291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a gun bug and the gun team corrected it this morning. After the error was corrected and I updated gun in my project, I was still left with problems bundling with webpack:

```
WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bufferutil' in /node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 10:19-40

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'utf-8-validate' in /node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:19-44

WARNING in ./~/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js
Critical dependencies:
1:43-50 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js 1:43-50

WARNING in ./~/formidable/lib/file.js
Critical dependencies:
1:43-50 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/formidable/lib/file.js 1:43-50

WARNING in ./~/formidable/lib/json_parser.js
Critical dependencies:
1:43-50 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/formidable/lib/json_parser.js 1:43-50

WARNING in ./~/formidable/lib/querystring_parser.js
Critical dependencies:
1:43-50 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/formidable/lib/querystring_parser.js 1:43-50

WARNING in ./~/aws-sdk/lib/util.js
Critical dependencies:
40:30-45 the request of a dependency is an expression
43:11-53 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/aws-sdk/lib/util.js 40:30-45 43:11-53

WARNING in ./~/aws-sdk/lib/api_loader.js
Critical dependencies:
13:15-59 the request of a dependency is an expression
104:12-46 the request of a dependency is an expression
108:21-58 the request of a dependency is an expression
114:18-52 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/aws-sdk/lib/api_loader.js 13:15-59 104:12-46 108:21-58 114:18-52
```

I had to add the following to my webpack.config.js to use gun with webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  target: "node", 

....

  module: {
    noParse: [/aws-sdk/],

....

 plugins: [
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "global.GENTLY": false })
 ]
....
```

At that point everything was working even though I still had the following errors in bash:

```
WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bufferutil' in /node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 10:19-40

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'utf-8-validate' in /node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:19-44
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear our fix we pushed resolved the major issue. Hopefully eventually we can also get these last few annoying WARNING/ERROR messages to go away. Thanks for answering yourself, it is really appreciated!

Comment: Since this is a known issue that @marknadal and friends are working on, I went ahead and used `stats:{warnings:false}` as my dirty solution to reduce the noise.

Comment: @aleksblago oh, what did that help / fix the issue also? I am going to add another answer about require('gun/gun');

Comment: @marknadal Nice! It disables all warnings being output by webpack, which is why I called it a "dirty solution". Ideally those warnings should be addressed but for my particular use case/test, the fix outlined in the answer did the trick. I just added the line I mentioned to remove the two remaining warnings jtlindsey described above. I wasn't doing anything special or complex so I knew the only thing that'd be throwing warnings was gun.

Answer (score 1):

For now, in the browser you ought to:

```
var Gun = require('gun/gun');
```

To fix your issue. Or use a script tag, which exports Gun globally.

In the future, we'll try and have require('gun') auto-detect environment and not auto-include NodeJS only code (like `fs`, websockets, http, etc.)